# Is Paypal REST API direct credit card payment allowed for merchants in the Philippines?

Tags: paypal

I have an application that needs to accept credit card as the payment method. The customers will enter their credit card info on my website. PayPal API supports direct credit card payment but I'm not sure if it is allowed in my country (Philippines).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you were referring to **Direct Credit Card Payments (REST API)**, the PayPal REST API supports direct credit card payments, which are credit card payments without a separate web approval flow, in the following countries:

```
Canada
United States
United Kingdom
```

Please refer to:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/#direct-credit-card-payments

So no, unfortunately it is not currently available in the Philippines.

Comment: What about the classic API direct credit card payment? Is that available in the Philippines?

Comment: Unfortunately classic API direct credit card payment is not available in the Philippines. Only for PRO accounts in UK, US and Canada.

Comment: I'm confused, does this mean that a US PayPal Pro REST API app is unable to accept credit card payments from customers outside of the US and UK? Or, does this mean that only PayPal Pro merchants in the US and UK can use the REST API for their app/store, but can accept payments from customers anywhere?

Answer (score 6):

REST is not available in Canada - even though the documentation says it is. We went through the whole exercise to put the API in place to find out it's not available - and probably will never be available. This is directly from the Partner Program head.

Comment: I've spent one week on testing with REST api and it was working. when I switch the mode from sandbox to "live" it gave me this information: 
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"}. Sad